# QT signal with struct in parameter

Tags: qt, signals, slot

I have the class :

```
class SupervisionManager : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT public:
    explicit SupervisionManager(ComAds* com, ComRegEtat* comEt,
                                ComRegOrdonnanceur* comOrdo,
                                QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SupervisionManager();  

protected:
    virtual void run();

private:
    void actionFromPlc();

    ComRegEtat::Antichoc antichoc;


signals:
    void majAntichoc(ComRegEtat::Antichoc&);
};
```

and the implementation:

```
void SupervisionManager::run() {
    manage=true;

    while(manage)
    {
        actionFromPlc();
        usleep(5000);
    }
}


void SupervisionManager::actionFromPlc() {
    antichoc.SAS = false;
    emit majAntichoc(antichoc);
}
```

And I connect this signal with :

```
connect(manager, SIGNAL(majAntichoc(ComRegEtat::Antichoc&)),
        preparation, SLOT(affichageAntichoc(ComRegEtat::Antichoc&)));
```

How do to emit a signal with a `struct` in its parameter list?
I think I have to use a `QSignalMapper` but I don't understand how.

Comment: What is the problem with using plain emit? Why do you think that you should use QSignalMapper?

Comment: so what happens when your mentioned code executes ?

Answer (score 0):

In absolutely same way as you emit other things..

```
ComRegEtat::Antichoc  myStruct;
.. some initialisation code
emit majAntichoc(myStruct);
```

I dont know for sure about latest Qt (after they changed signals/slot be templates based), but before 'emit' was just empty define, so you should look on emit like on function call...

Comment: I wonder if you need to register emitted type as `QMetaType` using `qRegisterMetaType`. Have you tested it?

Comment: I used such pattern some time ago, and honestly don't think you need qRegisterMetaType for that.

Comment: QRegisterMetaType/Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is only needed for queued connections, not for direct connections (the default in single-threaded code)

Answer (score 0):

With my code, the slot isn't called whereas the signal is emitted.

I found the solution :

```
signals:
    void majAntichoc(ComRegEtat::Antichoc *);
```

and

```
slot : 
    void affichageAntichoc(ComRegEtat::Antichoc *);
```

And I don't have to use a `QSignalMapper`.

Thanks